# 2019 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2019 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://academia.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Where and when do we see who did nominate?

Comment: @user114084 They will be displayed at the election link above. You will also see their answers to the questions filter in at: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/2019-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire The typical nomination period is 7 days, and in my experience with past elections on other sites usually it takes a bit for candidates to shuffle in.

Comment: Okay, thank you!